# How can I implement the dash.callback_context function in django_ploty_dash environment?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, dashboard, plotly-dash

I would like to know which Input is requiring the callback. This solution works well with dash.

```py
@app.callback(
Output('medcode', 'value'),
[Input('pie-toptenR', 'clickData'),
Input('pie-toptenM', 'clickData')])
def update_medcode(clickData, clickData2):
    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if (clickData==None) & (clickData2==None):
        return ''
    else:
        pie = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]
        if pie == 'pie-toptenR':
            return clickData['points'][0]['label']
        else:
            return clickData2['points'][0]['label']
```